# Python IDE for Data Analysis

Tags: python, ide, rstudio, data-analysis

Python can be used for many tasks. I want to use Python for data analysis. What Python IDEs are particular good for data analysis tasks.

As a reference for a data analysis specific IDE, please see RStudio for the R language.

Answer (score 1):

`Ipython`

I test most of my `numpy` and `scipy` answers in `Ipython`.

A couple of new books are:

http://ipython.org/books.html

> Learning IPython for Interactive Computing and Data Visualization
>
> IPython Interactive Computing and Visualization Cookbook

Answer (score 1):

What has recently released [Rodeo](http://blog.yhathq.com/posts/introducing-rodeo.html), which is explicitly focussed on data analysis and looks a LOT like RStudio as you can see in this screenshot. If you want something that is a bit more scientific computing generally, rather than specifically data analysis, the other good one is [Spyder](https://pythonhosted.org/spyder/), particularly through the [Anaconda distribution](https://www.continuum.io/downloads), which includes all the important scientific packages.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as how there are already two votes to close I just want to mention that the two tools that have come up in my searches are [IEP](http://www.iep-project.org/) and [Spyder](https://code.google.com/p/spyderlib/). I have not yet evaluated them, but when I do I will update this answer with more details.

Answer (score 0):

PyCharm works fine for me. It has plug-ins for database access and supports multiple languages. There is a plug-in for R, but I didn't use it so far.
The integrated shells (Python and bash) are also good to quickly try something.

IPython notebook is fine especially for explorative work. But the editing support is not that great IMHO. There is also no source control and other functionality for developing software.

Answer (score 0):

Spider is best editor.It is default editor in anaconda distribution.So install anaconda distribution.Anaconda distribution includes almost all packages used in data analysis.It provides the advanced editing, interactive testing, debugging and introspection features.

Anaconda distibution : https://www.continuum.io/downloads
Spyder link : https://pythonhosted.org/spyder/

Answer (score 0):

I suggest jupyter notebook..best for data analysis..
2nd preference -- spyder..
Just install anaconda python. 
You'll get inbuild Jupyter notebook, spyder IDE's

Answer (score 0):

PyCharm is perfect for those who already have experience using another JetBrain’s IDE, due to the fact that the interface and features be similar. Also, if you like IPython or Anaconda distribution, it’s nice for you to know that PyCharm integrates its tools and libraries such as NumPy and Matplotlib, allowing you work with array viewers and interactive plots.

In addition to Python, PyCharm provides support for Scientific mode.Scientific mode in PyCharm provides support for interactive scientific computing and data visualization.

Features Just like other IDEs, PyCharm has interesting features such as a code editor, errors highlighting, a powerful debugger with a graphical interface, besides of Git integration, SVN, and Mercurial. You can also customize your IDE, choosing between different themes, color schemes, and key-binding. Additionally, you can expand PyCharm’s features by adding plugins; You can take a look at the PyCharm Plugins Library.